# Issue with Commissions Calculator

Tags: java, jgrasp

```
import java.util.Scanner; // imports scanner class to read user input

public class commissionsCalc { //opens class 



public static void main(String[] args){// opens main


  double commissionsRate;
  int basePay = 1000;
  int monthlySales = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  double grossPay = 0;
  double commissionsAmt;
  int curSale = 0;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  //System.out.println("Please enter a sale amount or type -1 to finish entering sales and calculate gross pay");



  System.out.println("Please enter a sale amount or type -1 to finish entering sales and calculate gross pay");  
  curSale = input.nextInt();

  while (curSale !=-1) {//opens while loop

     monthlySales += curSale;
     counter++;

     System.out.println("Please enter a sale amount or type -1 to finish entering sales and calculate gross pay");  
     curSale = input.nextInt();

  }//closes while loop

  if (monthlySales < 5000){//opens if statement
     commissionsRate = .06;
  }//closes if statement

  else if (monthlySales > 5000 && monthlySales <10000) {//opens else if statement
     commissionsRate = .08;

  } 
  else if (monthlySales >= 10000) {//opens else if statement
     commissionsRate = .10;
```

I need to calculate the monthlySales but I'm not sure how I add up all the Current sales in my loop. Also need to display the commissionsRate when the user comes up with the sales. I'm just not sure how I can do that. I'm using Jgrasp/java.

Comment: You are adding your curSale to your montlySales in your current loop

Comment: Yes now im not sure how I print the value i get from all the numbers to the screen

Comment: can you post complete code so that I can take a stab at it?

Comment: yes, how do i do that, im new to this site

Comment: Paste your full code like you posted code in the question?

Comment: Ok i think it worked

Comment: you are just looking to print all the values? System.out.println will do that

Comment: Yes im trying to print my monthly sales, the commission rate to those sales, how much commission i made of those sales, and the total gross pay. I realize system print will do that but i dont know how to calculate those.

Comment: let me know if that solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this in your code

```
commissionsAmt = monthlySales*commissionsRate;
grossPay = basePay + commissionsAmt;
System.out.println("Monthly sales amount is: "+ monthlySales);
System.out.println("Commision rates to those sales: "+ commissionsRate);
System.out.println("Commission amount made "+ commissionsAmt);
System.out.println("Gross pay "+ grossPay);
```

Comment: i get an error message saying java:56: error: variable commissionsRate might not have been initialized

Comment: I had a typo. I updated it now and also initialize commissionsRate to zero

Comment: Thanks one more thing, how do i get it to print my base pay?

Comment: Same way have a println statement and print your basePay variable there

Comment: System.out.println("Base Pay: ", basePay)?

Comment: i get an error message saying no suitable method found for println(String,int)

Comment: It's not a comma (,) it's a plus (+) like System.out.println("Base Pay: "+basePay)

Comment: Glad I could help!